# Load different image based on screen width

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xhtml, responsive-design

Lets assume that I'm calling an image like

```
<img src="http://server:8080/graphs/ChartGen?PID=982&minutes=480&height=30&width=1400" />
```

Where the width is "1400" at the end, how can I make that "1400", 60% of the users screen width instead?

Comment: don't know if I understand your question but maybe css will help: img {width:60%}

Comment: Unfortunately the source of the image requires that I pass a value to it (width=1400 at the end) therefore a 1400 might be too large if I am running the code on a 900px wide display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I sort of added my answer to the one that noway had provided since my actual image string was a bit more complicated than his answer would allow for as it was inside a jsp loop.

```
<%
    for (int i = 0; rs.next(); i++) {
%>

//Other formatting
<div class="ProgramGraph"> 
<script type="text/javascript"> document.write("<img src=\"http://server07:8080/graphs/ChartGen?PID=<%= rs.getInt("PID")%>&minutes=<%out.print(timeSelected * 60);%>&height=30&width=" +screen.width*.60 +"\" />");</script></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set the parameter in JavaScript. Check the source of Google Books.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">     

var url= "http://server:8080/graphs/ChartGen?PID=982&minutes=480&height=30&width=" + (screen.width * 0.60);     


</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution wouldn't work since the PID / minutes also need to change based on user preference.   Those values are loaded via loop.

Comment: I believe you can also set the PID and minutes parameters with another JS function which is fired on the Click event of links?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use CSS instead of JS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    #Chart {
        background-image: url(//server:8080/chart/982/480/:height:30/:width:480);
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 799px) {
    #Chart {
        background-image: url(//server:8080/chart/982/480/:height:30/:width:460);
    }
}
...
```

Though charts tend to be part of the content, so using CSS and `background-image` isn't really appropriate, and JS + `img.src` is the better approach in this case.